# How can I set the `sub` claim of a JWT in FeathersJS?

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

The `sub` claim for JWTs is optional, but the feathersjs-authentication won't let me set it to a blank string or remove it.

I was able to add a new value to the payload in the `authentication` before `hook` but changing `sub` or trying to remove it doesn't work.

```
app.service('/api/auth').hooks({
  before: {
    create: [
      // You can chain multiple strategies
      auth.hooks.authenticate(['jwt', 'local']),

      hook => {
        // I can add a new `SUB` value but this method doesn't work for `sub`
        Object.assign(hook.params.payload, {SUB: hook.params.payload.userId})
      }
    ],
...
```

I tried adding the same change to the `after` hook, but that didn't work either. Having the `sub` value as `anonymous` doesn't seem right to me. Their docs even say:

`subject: 'anonymous', // Typically the entity id associated with the JWT`

Yet there does not seem to be a straight-forward way to make the `sub` JWT claim a dynamic value.

Answer (score 2):

The `subject` or `sub` is set in the [authentication options](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/server.html#default-options) and - like any other JWT specific option - can not be set through the payload.

[Looking at the code](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/master/src/service.js#L22) you can see that [valid JWT option keys](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/master/src/utils.js#L9-L24) can be set through `params` (which other than `params.query` is outside of a malicious client reach so it can't be easily tampered with):

```
app.service('/api/auth').hooks({
  before: {
    create: [
      // You can chain multiple strategies
      auth.hooks.authenticate(['jwt', 'local']),

      hook => {
        hook.params.jwt.subject = hook.params.payload.userId;
      }
    ],
```

Comment: Not working :( Still coming out as `anonymous`. I tried in the `before` and `after` hook; same result.

Comment: Actually you need to set hook.params.jwt.subject = hook.params.payload.userId

Comment: @SomethingOn checkmate. I was struggling to understand why it returned my user.name instead of ID. Shook: my username was called `anonymous`, which for my surprise it's the same returned by default

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own `authenticationStrategy` by extending `authenticationService` and using `getTokenOptions()` to overwrite the payload sub for that you need to work on also how will you verify it.

Scenario : I wanted to encrypt my sub for that I created a new `AuthClass` extending `AuthService` and overriding

```
async getTokenOptions(
    authResult: AuthenticationResult,
    params: Params
  ): Promise<any> {
    const secret = this.app.get('authentication').secret;
    const { user } = authResult;
    const { id } = user;
    const payload = await super.getTokenOptions(authResult, params);
    if (user && user.id) {
      payload.subject = encrypt(id, secret);
    }
    return payload;
  }
```

and also I need to decrypt at the time of adding it `params.user`, so I created another `jwtDecryptStrategy` extending given `JWTStrategy` and override its `getEntityId()` to return the decrypted id

Like this:

```
export class JwtDecryptStrategy extends JWTStrategy {
  async getEntityId(
    authResult: AuthenticationResult,
    _params: Params
  ): Promise<any> {
    return decrypt(
      authResult.authentication.payload.sub,
      this.app?.get('authentication').secret
    );
  }
}
```