# How can I change the JWT expire time in FeathersJS?

Tags: jwt, hook, feathersjs

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974114/how-can-i-set-the-sub-claim-of-a-jwt-in-feathersjs) on how to set the sub claim of a JWT in FeathersJS, but when I print `hook.params`, there is no `jwt` in there.
Only `authenticated`, `query`, `route`, `provider`, `headers`, `user` and `payload`.

So I remain with the question: how can I change the expire time of a JWT token in Feathers?

Answer (score 9):

Found it :) 
I took a look at the code linked in the post (link has changed, but found it back easily when browsing the git repo) and saw that in `params`, you just need to create your own `jwt` object and these options will be merged when creating the JWT.

So, if anyone else stumbles upon this, here is my code:

```
app.service('authentication').hooks({
  before: {
    create: [
      authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies),

      context => {
        context.params.jwt = { expiresIn: 10 }; // 10 seconds
      }
    ],
    remove: [
      authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that expiration time isn't enforced automatically... in auth v2. https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/1338
A fake year long JWT would pass the default validation, even if your config has 10m JWT expiration. If someone sees you issuing year long JWT's... you're asking for trouble. Validate the expiration with the algorithm used... a long expiration should use a good algorithm like https://auth0.com/blog/brute-forcing-hs256-is-possible-the-importance-of-using-strong-keys-to-sign-jwts/#JWT-Signing-Algorithms

Answer (score 7):

For posterity,

you can easily change that in config/default.json:

```
{
  // ...
  "authentication": {
    "jwtOptions": {
        "expiresIn": "2 days" // Or "10h" or just a number which is interpreted as seconds
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an easier, yet general approach. The code I posted above can be used when you want to limit session time for a certain user for instance.